# boost::fusion::zip function vs boost::fusion::zip_view

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

I'm painfully trying to learn boost fusion and I dont understand clearly the differences between zip_view and the result of zip function.

```
namespace fuz = boost::fusion;

typedef fuz::vector<int,int> vec1;
typedef fuz::vector<char,char> vec2;
typedef fuz::vector<vec1&, vec2&> sequences;

typedef fuz::zip_view<sequences> zip_view_type;

typedef fuz::result_of::zip<vec1, vec2>::type zip_result_type;

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((boost::is_same<zip_view_type, zip_result_type>));
```

- I expected the two types to be the same, but they are not. Why?
- zip_view and zip function seems to be very closely related but I dont
  see when / why using the view instead of the function.

Comment: According to the documentation of `zip_view`, `sequences` should be `fuz::vector<vec1&,vec2&>`. `result_of::zip` seems to use `vector2` instead of `vector` internally, so if you use `vector2` in `vec1`, `vec2` and `sequences` the types seem to be the same ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2bc2f794e33c64c)). Hopefully someone who knows more will give you a better answer.

Comment: @cv_and_he : thx, at least your live example demonstrates the diff. I tried to use type_info too but with g++ (even with name demangling) the output was too cryptic. I will also correct the sequences typedef in my question.

Comment: Ok `vector2` is just the numbered form of 2 elements vector. `vector` is the variadic form. What I understand here is that `result_of::zip<vec1, vec2>::type` will use the numbered form of vector and zip_view will use the type of the given sequence, thus here : the variadic form of vector( `vector<vec1&, vec2&>`).

Answer (score 3):

I hope I can answer your second question (why using `zip_view` instead of `zip`).

The matter is that `zip` produces a sequence of tuples containing **constant** references to respective elements of zipped sequences. In your example it is `vector2<const int&, const char&>`

In contrast, references in tuples produced by `zip_view` for each element have the same const qualifier as zipped sequence in the view constructor. It will be `vector<int&, char&>` in your case.

As a result, `zip_view` allows something that `zip` does not support:

1. Modification of elements of zipped sequences;
2. Selection of sequences to be modified.